# VHDL USB UART Problem

Tags: fpga, vhdl, uart, rs232

I've just described an UART transmitter and receiver in VHDL. In simulation everything seems to be fine. In FPGA, the loopback interface works well: I push a button, the transmitter sends data, the receiver receives and display in the 7 segment display.

Regarding communication between laptop and FPGA, I am using a USB<->RS232 cable. Using GtkTerm on linux and tera term on windows I can easily send data to the FPGA. The problem is when I try to send data from FPGA to laptop: just a few bytes arrive in the laptop and many of these bytes are wrong. For instance, I send EE EE EE EE EE EE EE, but I receive only EE CF 14.

I have no idea of what the problem is: if it is software (maybe I've configured something wrong or a driver issue?); if it is hardware (faulty cable?) or if it is code (my VHDL code is wrong).

Any ideas on how to solve the issue?

p.s.: I've tried some few uart transmitters besides mine, they also send just a few bytes.
p.s2.: some info: 19200 baud; 8 bits of data, no parity bit, 1 stop bit

if code is needed: https://github.com/hdhzero/hivek-io-modules/blob/master/uart/src/uart_tx.vhd

Comment: What clock are you giving the module? What does your surrounding top-level look like?

Comment: The system clock is 50MHz. The clock feeds a mod counter that generates an enable tick for the transmitter and receiver modules

Comment: All the modules can be found at https://github.com/hdhzero/hivek-io-modules/tree/master/uart/src. top_uart_controller is the top level where I make the pin assignemnts. Uart_controller.vhd basically create instances of the tx, rx and mod counter

Comment: @hdzero: why do you count 16 ticks in your `tx` module and 8 in `rx`?

Comment: @Qiu In rx, I wait for the first '0' level, then I switch to the data_bits states. I use 16 ticks to sample data, so the middle of the bit is between seven~eight. I simple take advantage of the fact that the counter will overflow automatically. So when it reaches 7, then I set it to 8 (or I could just let it increment). When I set to 8, the counter goes: 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7, which is just the middle of the following incoming bit

Comment: I really dont know what the problem is... I've already tested the design on linux and windows. I've also tried three or four implementations I've found in the internet. Today, I am going to buy a new usb-rs232 cable and see if the problem persists. Also, I will try to test on another FPGA. But for the moment, I have no clue of what is the problem

Comment: Which USB-UART chip do you use (e.g. FDDI, CP2103, ...) I experienced a faulty CP2103 on a VC707 board which has a baud rate deviation of over 15%, so the last one or two bits come in wrong. One way to check your UART is a simple chipscope core (64k cycles deep, 2 bits (rx,tx), data=trigger, sampled on falling edge). So you can see what is going on on the wire and you can measure the bit times in cycles. If you don't have enough BRAM, you can use a 10 MHz clock from a free DCM/PLL port to drive chipscope or you use your tick-signal as a storage-qualifier in chipscope (advanced technique :) )

Comment: @Paebbels I'm not sure what the chipset is (I've found the cable in the laboratory). It doesn't has any info in the cable (chipset, etc). When I plug on linux and run lsusb, I got a CH340 chipset (this cable: http://www.ayagroup.com/product.php?productid=19576)

Comment: Uh this is bad. I never got this CH340 running. Driver issues/couldn't active COM port. I switched to CP2103 which supports up to 921 kbit/s

Comment: @Paebbels So your guess is that the problem is really the cable?

Comment: No that's not my guess, but you should also  consider low-level debugging. It costs me 1 week of debugging and a additioal day to proof this fauöty behaviour to my colleages :) so be prepared for everything

Answer (score 1):

It was really a faulty cable. I don't know if the problem is the chipset itself or a wire. Anyway, I bought a new cable with a different chipset and everything is ok now!

This is the faulty one

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter
```

This is the one that worked

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
```